# How can I scroll to specific row in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, scroll

I'm currently highlighting the matching row in the gridview, but to view it I have to scroll down. I would like to set the position of the scroll bar such that the matching record is always visible.

```
protected void MatchGrid_OnRowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Row.RowType  == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

        //bool ismatch = (bool)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.Cells, e.Row.Cells[2].Text ="Main");
        //if (ismatch) e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#FAF7DA"); 

        // Highlights the selected row and makes the text bold
        if (e.Row.Cells[2].Text.ToLower() == txtHouseNumber.Text.ToLower() && e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToLower() == txtStreetName.Text.ToLower())
        {
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<b>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</b>";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = "<b>" + e.Row.Cells[2].Text + "</b>";
            e.Row.Cells[3].Text = "<b>" + e.Row.Cells[3].Text + "</b>";
            e.Row.BackColor = Color.FromName("#FAF7DA");
            //This is what I was trying to use 
            GV_NEMOAddresses.SelectedIndex = e.Row.RowIndex;
        }
    }

}
```

I would prefer to do this without Javascript if possible.

Comment: Use GridView1.SelectedRow.Focus() check this too http://microsoftmiles.blogspot.com/2006/11/maintaining-gridview-scroll-position-in.html